# Delay displaying UI in cross platform app on ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, monaca

I have a cross platform app built using Monaca and AngularJS.

On some screens I display a generic view, and then display certain sections based on the outcome of some calculations/lookups using ***ng-if*** and ***ng-include***.

E.g. for the Login screen, I display a generic view, while in my controller I check whether the user has logged in before. Depending on the outcome of this lookup, I either show a Welcome message OR prompt the user to Login.

Below is a abbreviated version of the generic *login* view.

```
<div>
    <ons-page>
        <ons-scroller >
            <!-- Show if user not logged in -->
            <div ng-if="!loggedIn">
                <div ng-include="'login/login-details.html'"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Show if user logged in -->
            <div ng-if="loggedIn">
                <div ng-include="'login/login-confirmation.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </ons-scroller>
    </ons-page>
</div>
```

This is working fine but the issue is that the first ***ng-if*** is always shown - even just for a second - while the controller checks if the user is logged in and then sets the value of ***loggedIn***. So the user always sees the login prompt until the controller returns true or false on the variable ***loggedIn***.

The boolean value for ***loggedIn*** is just defined but not initialed in the controller. It only gets initiated once the lookup has been done.

How can I stop both the ***ng-include*** s from displaying till I know which one to display?

I can create another ***ng-if*** but it seems long winded and inefficient.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe `ng-cloak` will help. If not just add `ng-show` with the same condition like in `ng-if`.

Comment: I can't tell what's going on in your controller/service(s), but you're probably not using a promise.

Comment: @Ben Beck - No Im not using a promise. I am using a asynchronous call to check if the user is logged in, which makes the lookup even longer. I will try ng-cloak and if that doesnt work Ill implement a promise.

Comment: It can also be that your login callback mechanism is not angular based (i.e triggered by something like `window.addEventListener`) then the callback is not angular aware and no digest is triggered. Then a simple `$scope.$applyAsync()` solves the problem. Moreover the one second delay sounds like the angular auto digest triger.

Answer (score 1):

I would also use the ng-show and hide the items until they are evaluated using the ng-hide class, see below:

```
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="!loggedIn">
    <div ng-include="'login/login-details.html'"></div>
</div>
<!-- Show if user logged in -->
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="loggedIn">
    <div ng-include="'login/login-confirmation.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One method you can use is if `loggedIn` is `null` or `undefined` until you check weather the user is logged in, you can use a strict comparison operator `===` for `true` and `false` like so:

```
<div>
    <ons-page>
        <ons-scroller >
            <!-- Show if user not logged in -->
            <div ng-if="loggedIn === false">
                <div ng-include="'login/login-details.html'"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Show if user logged in -->
            <div ng-if="loggedIn === true">
                <div ng-include="'login/login-confirmation.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </ons-scroller>
    </ons-page>
</div>
```

This would ensure that neither gets displayed until the outcome of your "lookup".

Another solution to the problem, depending on your choice of routing, would be to make use of [`ngRoute`'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)s or [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)'s `resolve` property. This way you can check if the user is logged in before the view is loaded.